# Viewing Word Documents inside Browsers

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, ms-word, applet, activex

I'm searching for some kind of Programm / Java Applet / ActiveX Control or magic spell to **view** Word / Excel Documents inside Browsers (Browser independent would be the best case, but IE only ist just fine).

I don't want to open Word itsself inside a frame, because that gives users the false impression that they can edit and save the document i just want to display its contents.

I also found solutions which converts the word document to pdf first, but i can't do this due to some security restrictions on the environment i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

This can help when those proprietary file formats can first be converted to ODF (for example by LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org): http://webodf.org/

(I will not comment on "security restrictions" and using Microsoft software ...)